# Draw a directed graph in Python

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a data table and I want to show it by a directed graph. My table is following:

```
point,previous_point
"A","-"
"B","-"
"C","A"
"D","B"
"E","C"
"F","C"
"G","D,E"
"H","F,G"
```

And I need a graph drawn using by the above data. The graph I want is:
[image]

I have tried with the networkx package. But the result is not good. Someone can help me improve the graph? Besides, I also want to automatically draw with input data like the above table.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edges_from(
[('Start','A'),('Start','B'),
('A','C'),('B','D'),('C','E'),('C','F'),
 ('D','G'),('E','G'),('F','H'),('G','H'),
 ('H','End')])

 nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
 plt.show()
```

Comment: What does "the result is not good" mean?

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust the layout of your plot like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import pydot
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import graphviz_layout

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edges_from(
[('Start','A'),('Start','B'),
('A','C'),('B','D'),('C','E'),('C','F'),
('D','G'),('E','G'),('F','H'),('G','H'),
('H','End')])

pos = graphviz_layout(G, prog="dot")
for k,v in pos.items():
    pos[k]=(-v[1],v[0])

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos = pos, node_shape = 's', node_size = 200, 
                       node_color = 'none', edgecolors='k')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos = pos, 
                       node_shape = 's', width = 1,  node_size = 200)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos = pos, font_size = 5)

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: Result]

If you want to get exactly the result, you have showed above, you may want to generate the positions yourself and pass them to the draw commands.

Comment: How do you get rectangles? I implement this piece of code and I get circles...

Comment: @Newbielp `node_shape = 's'` added as an argument to the node drawing command should give you squares.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `networkx` one could use `mermaid`. Here's a chart generated online at `https://mermaid.live`:

```
graph LR
    A --> C --> E --> G --> H
    C --> F --> H
    B --> D --> G
```

[image]

Of course, there is scope for adjusting it to suit your needs. Once the desired format is found, it should be feasible to use Python to restructure the original table into format suitable for `mermaid`.

Comment: Mermaid is a library written in JavaScript, so if OP wants something they can work with in Python alone, that's not going to be it.

Comment: @AKX: well... sure, the question is specifically referring to Python, but Python is flexible enough to generate the output format for `mermaid` (e.g. by embedding in a markdown)... anyway, it's a workable alternative, not worth the downvote IMO.

Comment: It's not a workable alternative if OP wants e.g. an image to be rendered in Python.